# Show the modal when user click the form button and submit the form when user click the modal button in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

View:

```
<form role="form" id="formfield" 
action="invoice/add_invoice" method="post">

<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="courier" 
name="courier"></div>

<div class="form-group"><label>Last Name</label><input class="form-control" 
name="lastname" id="lastname"></div>

<div class="form-group"><label>First Name</label><input class="form-control"
name="firstname" id="firstname"></div>

<input type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn- 
default"/>

</form>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
           <th>Last Name</th>
           <td id="lname"></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="invoice/add_invoice" id="submit" class="btn btn-success 
success">Submit</a>
</div>
</div></div></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
   $('#confirm-submit').modal('show);
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
  $('#formfield').submit();
});
```

When I click submit button it opens the modal with particular form datas and after that I click submit button in modal, submit the form datas but, in my case it submit the modal datas because of I am using href in modal.Now I want to submit form datas what can I do??Any alternate method is there to do this please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You have to change href text.Please try javascript:void(); or replace anchor with  button 
Replace below code and try again

Answer (score 0):

So the correction is in modal, instead of href use button to submit the form.

Modal:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal-button" 
value="OK">
```

Jquery:

```
//when you click form button it opens the modal

$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
   $('#confirm-submit').modal('show);
});


//when you click modal button it submit the form datas.

$('#modal-button').click(function(){
  $('#formfield').submit();  //formfield is form id
});
```